# passing javascript variable to html for display

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following

```
var loan = parseFloat(document.getElementById("loanamount"));

document.getElementById('numpay').textContent = loan.toString();
```

and my html is this:

```
<p>Number of Payments:    <a id="numpay"> </a> </p>
```

I feel like this should be working but cannot seem to get anything other than NaN in my html, no matter how I configure it. I know I am a novice at javascript but could you please give me a tip?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the tag with id `loanamount`?

Comment: Why are you parsing a float and then stringifying it?

Comment: just curious but I would imagine the value you're pulling back is a string as you are parsing it with `parseFloat`. Then in the next line you're calling `.toString()`. Seems a little counter productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `parseFloat(document.getElementById("loanamount").value)` most probably

*TIP:* Instead of `parseFloat`, just use `+` to convert from strings to numbers. So `+document.getElementById("loanamount").value` should also serve your purpose.

Comment: This was a very complete answer and thus I accept it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var loan = parseFloat(document.getElementById("loanamount").value);

document.getElementById('numpay').textContent = loan.toString();
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, I will look into javascripts .value more, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't doing anything with `loan` then just do this:

```
document.getElementById('numpay').textContent = document.getElementById("loanamount").value
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element with id loanamount is an input you will need .getElementById("loanamount").value, if it is a span or div then .getElementById("loanamount").innerHTML. For writing back the same apply.

But in either case you must not use .toString() on the write in. parseFloat() will give you a number, which does not have methods. JavaScript is not that similar to Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var loan = parseFloat(document.getElementById("loanamount").value);

  document.getElementById('numpay').innerHTML = loan.toFixed(2);
```